# MS SSAS 2012 - You can only open files that are compatible with Microsoft SQL Server 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ssas, tabular, sql-server-2012-datatools

I am trying to create a new Analysis Services Tabular Project with SQL Server Data Tools in the VS 2010 shell. As soon as I click ok I get the error that the file cannot be opened. Both the client tools and the server or at 11.0.3000.0.

## Here are the details:

## Error Message:

### This file cannot be opened. You can only open files that are compatible with Microsoft SQL Server 2012.

An error occurred while opening the model on the workspace database. Reason: This file cannot be opened. You can only open files that are compatible with Microsoft SQL Server 2012.

============================

## Call Stack:

### at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.VSHost.VSHostManager.PrepareSandbox(Boolean newProject, Boolean& isRefreshNeeded, Boolean& isImpersonationChanged, Boolean& saveRequired, List`1& truncatedTables, Boolean isRealTimeMode)

at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.VSHost.VSHostManager.PrepareSandbox(Boolean newProject, Boolean& isRefreshNeeded, Boolean& isImpersonationChanged, Boolean& saveRequired, List`1& truncatedTables, Boolean isRealTimeMode)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.VSHost.Integration.EditorFactory.CreateEditorInstance(UInt32 grfCreateDoc, String pszMkDocument, String pszPhysicalView, IVsHierarchy pvHier, UInt32 itemid, IntPtr punkDocDataExisting, IntPtr& ppunkDocView, IntPtr& ppunkDocData, String& pbstrEditorCaption, Guid& pguidCmdUI, Int32& pgrfCDW)

============================

Any ideas on what I am missing?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your workspace server (tools -> option -> analysis services) may be "SSAS dimensional", not "SSAS tabular". Or, if it is a tabluar, check if it was not installed as a dimensional and then changed to a tabular (believe me, it happened to me)

Comment: The strange thing is we can work on the project from a remote client. It is when we log into the local machine and try to work on it that we get the problem.

Comment: but did you check what I said?

Answer (score 0):

I just faced this same issue. I checked what Diego posted too. I have a Tabular project already working fine. Tried to create a new tabular SSAS project then got this error. My work around, In the new Project selection window, rather than select create a new "Analysis Services Tabular Project", I selected the "Import from Server(Tabular)" project, then imported the Tabular project that was working fine. Model.bim file opened up fine and I just need to adjust the model as I need. Sorry this is not a fix but it works for me.